# Direct sum of V1 = {A ∈ V : At = A} and V2 = {A ∈ V : At = −A} equals V = Mn(R)

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

> Be:
>
> - $V=M_n(ℝ)$
> - $V_1$ = {A ∈ V : $A^t$ = A}
> - $V_2$ = {A ∈ V : $A^t$ = -A}
>
> Knowing that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subspaces of V, prove that $V = V_1 ⊕ V_2$.

So, first of all, I already know how to prove that $V_1$ ⊕ $V_2$ is a direct sum.

To prove that V = $V_1$ ⊕ $V_2$, I need to prove that:

1. $V_1 ⊕ V_2 ⊂ V$, and
2. V ⊂ $V_1$ ⊕ $V_2$

Thanks to subspace properties, proving 1) is easy enough. But I couldn't prove 2). My Linear Algebra professor published his answer, which is something like:

> Take $A ∈ V$, and
>
> $B=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)$, and
>
> $C=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^t)$
>
> Therefore:
>
> $B^t=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)^t$
>
> $B^t=\frac{1}{2}(A^t+(A^t)^t)$
>
> $B^t=\frac{1}{2}(A^t+A)$
>
> $B^t=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)$, thus $B^t = B$ and B ∈ $v_1$
>
> Similarly, for C:
>
> $C^t=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^t)^t$
>
> $C^t=\frac{1}{2}(A^t-(A^t)^t)$
>
> $C^t=\frac{1}{2}(A^t-A)$
>
> $C^t=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^t)$, thus $C^t = -C$ and C ∈ $v_2$
>
> Thus: $B + C ∈ V_1 + V_2$, and $B + C = A$. Proving that $V_1 ⊕ V_2 ⊂ V$.

I kind of get the proof. But I can't muster the thought process which led him to come up with this:

> Take $A ∈ V$, and
>
> $B=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)$, and
>
> $C=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^t)$

And what that thought process was, is precisely what I'd like to know. (Different ways to prove what the question asks are welcome too).

Comment: Do you know about the even/odd parts of functions $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?  Specifically, the even part is $f_e(x) = \frac12(f(x)+f(-x))$ and the odd part is $f_o(x)=\frac12(f(x)-f(-x))$.  Do you see a similarity between these definitions and the ones for $B,C$?  (Both deal with linear maps $L$ such that $L\circ L$ is the identity map)

Comment: If you want to derive what $B$ and what $C$ should be, assume that $A=B+C$ where $B$ is symmetric and $C$ is antisymmetric. Then $A^T=B^T+C^T=B-C$. Adding the two equations gives that $A+A^T=2B$, and subtracting them gives $A-A^T=2C$. Rearranging gives you the result.